# Delphi SOAP Attachments stopped working - The connection with the server was reset

Tags: delphi, soap

I have a DELPHI XE5 web service and Win 32 client exchanging SOAP calls via IIS. It has been heavily used for many years. One function sends a PDF file as a Soap Attachment to the client.

This suddenly stopped working on my development machine (Win 7) about mid-July this summer, although no direct code changes were made. The same code continues to work in production setting with no issues. This must be something in my local machine, but I cannot find it. The server creates the file and sends it without issue. But then client waits about 2 minutes and gets an exception

> The connection with the server was reset

This is the case for any call which has a `TSoapAttachment` parameter, even if it is left null.

Comment: Fwiw, I have some strange things happening on my dev machine (then Win7 Pro 64 bit) in July prior to Win10's release, apparently to do with MS prepping it for upgrading.  Do you have an OS backup or restore point from before July?

Comment: Check the usual suspects: Antivirus software, firewall, ...

Comment: Same behaviour with Firewall turned OFF. And Antivirus turned OFF.

Comment: The only thing I find odd, from log files, is that the server creates file of, say, 200k but the soap packet is only 18k. My logging could be wrong, I'm using SOAPResponse.size in the AfterDispatch event.